# The more I close the modal, the more times the alert pops up

Tags: javascript, html, css

I ran into this problem the more often I close the modal window the more times the alert pops up. Most likely it has to do with the "if else" conditions, but I'm a beginner and can't figure out what exactly I set wrong. I tried to make one "if" inside the other but nothing works

[demonstration of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9deB.gif)

JS:

```
projectEditTitleBtn.forEach((btn) => {
    btn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        let data = e.target.dataset.modalOpen;
        modalTask.forEach((modal) => {
            if (modal.dataset.modal == data) {
                openModalEditProject(modal);
            }
        });

        modalAddBtn.forEach((modalAdd) => {
            modalAdd.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                if (projectNewTitle.value.length === 0 || "") {
                    alert("fields cannot be empty!");
                }
                if (projectNewTitle.value.length < 25 && projectNewTitle.value.length != 0) {
                    projectTitle.textContent = `${projectNewTitle.value}`;
                    sidebarProjectTitle.textContent = `${projectNewTitle.value}`;
                    const parentModal = this.closest(".modal");
                    parentModal.classList.remove("modal_state_active");
                    overlay.classList.remove("modal-bg_state_active");
                    modalBody.classList.remove("modal-body_state_active");
                    overlayProject.classList.remove("modal-bg_state_active");
                    projectModalBody.classList.remove("modal-body_state_active");
                    editProjectModalBody.classList.remove("modal-body_state_active");
                    editOverlayProject.classList.remove("modal-bg_state_active");
                }
                if (projectNewTitle.value.length > 25) {
                    alert("The name of the project can not be longer than 25 characters!");
                }
            });

            modalAdd.addEventListener("keypress", function (event) {
                if (projectNewTitle.value.length === 0 || "") {
                    alert("fields cannot be empty!");
                }

                if (event.key === "Enter" && projectNewTitle.value.length < 25 && projectNewTitle.value.length != 0) {
                    projectTitle.textContent = `${projectNewTitle.value}`;
                    sidebarProjectTitle.textContent = `${projectNewTitle.value}`;
                    const parentModal = this.closest(".modal");
                    parentModal.classList.remove("modal_state_active");
                    overlay.classList.remove("modal-bg_state_active");
                    modalBody.classList.remove("modal-body_state_active");
                    overlayProject.classList.remove("modal-bg_state_active");
                    projectModalBody.classList.remove("modal-body_state_active");
                    editProjectModalBody.classList.remove("modal-body_state_active");
                    editOverlayProject.classList.remove("modal-bg_state_active");
                }
                if (projectNewTitle.value.length > 25) {
                    alert("The name of the project can not be longer than 25 characters!");
                }
            });
        });
    });

    closeButtons.forEach(function (item) {
        item.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
            const parentModal = this.closest(".modal");
            parentModal.classList.remove("modal_state_active");
            overlay.classList.remove("modal-bg_state_active");
            modalBody.classList.remove("modal-body_state_active");
            overlayProject.classList.remove("modal-bg_state_active");
            projectModalBody.classList.remove("modal-body_state_active");
            editProjectModalBody.classList.remove("modal-body_state_active");
            editOverlayProject.classList.remove("modal-bg_state_active");
        });
    });

    cancelButtons.forEach(function (item) {
        item.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            const parentModal = this.closest(".modal");
            parentModal.classList.remove("modal_state_active");
            overlay.classList.remove("modal-bg_state_active");
            modalBody.classList.remove("modal-body_state_active");
            projectModalBody.classList.remove("modal-body_state_active");
            overlayProject.classList.remove("modal-bg_state_active");
            editProjectModalBody.classList.remove("modal-body_state_active");
            editOverlayProject.classList.remove("modal-bg_state_active");
        });
    });

function closeModal(e) {
    if (e.target.classList.contains("modal-bg")) {
        e.target.closest(".modal").classList.remove("modal_state_active");
        e.target.closest(".modal-bg").classList.remove("modal-bg_state_active");
        modalBody.classList.remove("modal-body_state_active");
        overlayProject.classList.remove("modal-bg_state_active");
        projectModalBody.classList.remove("modal-body_state_active");
        editProjectModalBody.classList.remove("modal-body_state_active");
        editOverlayProject.classList.remove("modal-bg_state_active");
    }
};

modalTask.forEach(modal => {
    modal.addEventListener('click', e => closeModal(e))
});

document.body.addEventListener("keyup",function (e) {
            const key = e.keyCode;
            if (key == 27) {
                document.querySelector(".modal.modal_state_active").classList.remove("modal_state_active");
                overlay.classList.remove("modal-bg_state_active");
                modalBody.classList.remove("modal-body_state_active");
                projectModalBody.classList.remove("modal-body_state_active");
                overlayProject.classList.remove("modal-bg_state_active");
                editProjectModalBody.classList.remove("modal-body_state_active");
                editOverlayProject.classList.remove("modal-bg_state_active");
            }
        },
        false
    );
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="modal modal_type_edit-project" data-modal="edit-project">
<div class="modal-bg modal-bg_type_edit-project">
    <div class="modal-body modal-body_type_edit-project">
        <div class="modal-content modal-callback">
            <div class="modal-callback__header">
                <h1 class="modal-callback__title">Change project name ‍</h1>
                <button class="modal-close">
                    <svg width="18" height="17" viewBox="0 0 18 17" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                        <path
                            fill-rule="evenodd"
                            clip-rule="evenodd"
                            d="M16.7659 0.338019C17.0892 0.654618 17.0892 1.16792 16.7659 1.48452L9.72132 8.38128L16.7659 15.2781C17.0893 15.5947 17.0893 16.108 16.7659 16.4246C16.4425 16.7412 15.9182 16.7412 15.5948 16.4246L8.72774 9.70155L1.86066 16.4246C1.53728 16.7412 1.01297 16.7412 0.689589 16.4246C0.366206 16.108 0.366206 15.5947 0.689589 15.2781L7.73413 8.38131L0.689558 1.48452C0.366176 1.16792 0.366176 0.654618 0.689558 0.338019C1.01294 0.0214211 1.53725 0.0214211 1.86063 0.338019L8.72771 7.06104L15.5948 0.338019C15.9182 0.0214211 16.4425 0.0214211 16.7659 0.338019Z"
                            fill="#787486"
                        />
                    </svg>
                </button>
            </div>
            <form class="modal-callback__form">
                <div class="modal-callback__labels">
                    <label class="modal-callback__label">
                        Enter new name
                        <input type="text" class="modal-callback__input modal-callback__input_type_edit-project" placeholder="enter new name of project" />
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-callback__btns">
                    <button class="modal-btn modal-btn_type_no-bg">Cancel</button>
                    <button class="modal-btn modal-btn_type_default modal-btn_type_edit-default">Save</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Would be easier to debug with a minimal reproductible example. Also what is `projectEditTitleBtn` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding event listeners in event listeners. Be very wary of doing this.

Every time the outer event listener is fired an additional event listener is added to the inner objects

E.g `modalAddBtn` is defined outside the scope of the `btn.addEventListener` function. Every time `btn` is clicked a new event listener will be added to `modalAddBtn`, resulting in multiple firings of the event.

Assign event listeners once.

Comment: Oh thank you so much, it really helped I took modalAddBtn outside of projectEditTitleBtn and everything worked

Answer (score 0):

My guess: Either you are adding more eventListener than you think in the forEach loops. OR your modal HTML nodes are re-used, BUT your eventlistener are never removed when closing the modal. I'm unsure where the brackets end in your snippet. You could try removing all added event listener when closing the modal. OR add the listeners just once, and not what it seems on each click.

You seem to be doing something like this

```js
// temp1 is an html element
temp1.addEventListener('click', () => {});
getEventListeners(temp1) // {click: Array(1)}

temp1.addEventListener('click', () => {});
getEventListeners(temp1) // {click: Array(2)}
```

`getEventListeners` allow you to see how many listener you have attached to that node. Add `console.log(getEventListeners(modalAdd))` right before each `modalAdd.addEventListener`, if the number of listeners keeps growing, you have you found the issue.